# NSURLRequest issue with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, webkit

I want to display a website in a WebView with Swift.
This is my code:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit


class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet var containerView : UIView! = nil
    var webView: WKWebView?

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()

        self.webView = WKWebView()
        self.view = self.webView!
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var url = NSURL(string:"http://www.google.de/")
        var req = NSURLRequest(URL:url)
        self.webView!.loadRequest(req)
    }

}
```

at `var req = NSURLRequest(URL:url)` I get an error,

> "Value of optional type 'NSURL?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use"!"...."

If I add the ! and run it, I got an runtime error,

> "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key browser"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var wv: UIWebView!


    func loadUrl(){
        wv.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://www.google.de/")!))
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        loadUrl()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<iOS_IITC.ViewController 0x7fbb42b790c0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key browser.'

Comment: try with the code above, just make sure you reconnect your outlet "wv" to your webview object at your view

Comment: if you are having problems with Xcode you might need to delete your Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData folder and also your Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode project file and restart your machine.